# How to allow multiple threads to read and write to a file without locking issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking

I have a web application that checks for the modification of a config.json file on each page load. It checks the modified date of the file and compares it against the last processing time that was recorded. If it differs, it proceeds to allow the reading of the file contents, processing those contents and updating config.json as well as writing to a separate file. I want to ensure that multiple simultaneous connections both reading and writing to these two files won't cause an issue.

```
var lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(ConfigJsonPath);
if (CacheTime != lastWriteTime)
{

  var config = new ConfigWriter().ReadData(ConfigJsonPath);
  var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StyleModel>(config);

  // This method writes to a another file
  ProcessConfig(model, page);
              
  var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented);
  new ConfigWriter().WriteData(serialized, ConfigJsonPath);
  CacheTime = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(ConfigJsonPath);

}
```

ConfigWriter Class

```
public class ConfigWriter
{
  private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim Lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
  public void WriteData(string data, string path)
  {
    Lock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
      using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
      {
        fs.SetLength(0);
        var dataAsByteArray = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(data);
        fs.Write(dataAsByteArray , 0, dataAsByteArray .Length);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      Lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
  }

  public string ReadData(string filePath)
  {
    Lock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
      string config;
      using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        using (var r = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
          config = r.ReadToEnd();
        }
      }
      return config;
    }
    finally
    {
      Lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
  }
}
```

So in the end there is one file being read, and two files being altered (write), and I'm using the same lock on the write.

Did I overdo it here? I started with a simple filestream with FileShare set to read/write, and then I got paranoid and second guessing myself. Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: @zgc7009 was hoping that was the benefit of using the `ReaderWriterLockSlim`

Comment: @user1447679 `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is exactly the right class for this task. The only thing is, it will only work if all the reading and writing code is using the same instance of the locking object. If it is, you should be good to go.

Comment: Curious why this is done from disk rather than memory- config files aren't large, and reading the entire thing into a memory object that's shared /accessed for config and can write out as a delayed/background task if it's updated would be more what I'd have expected...

Comment: @user1447679 deleting my comment. Don't want to confuse people. I'm newer to C# that's why I do comments not answers haha. That said, I'd still lean more towards what Caius said. But again I'm newer to this so...